# Ways to take a site offline for maintenance without killing running php started from http side?

Tags: php, linux, apache, apache2

I wrote a script `upload_songs.php`

When executed from the command line

```
$ php upload_songs.php
```

I can take the site offline

```
$ a2dissite my_website
$ service apache2 reload
```

and `upload_songs.php` will continue to run

However when I execute `upload_songs.php` from the http side by going to `my_website.com/upload_songs.php` if I do the following

```
$ a2dissite my_website
$ service apache2 reload
```

The php process `upload_songs.php` gets killed.  How can I take the site offline for maintenance without killing running php processes that have been started from the http side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apachectl graceful
```

This will wait until all connections are closed before restarting apache.

Docs for apachectl http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html

Comment: Thanks Adrian.  What if there's a lot of people online at the same time.  Does this command prevent new connections from being established (ex. new users trying to upload songs) while it's waiting until all connections are closed?

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I just tested this out.  Indeed running `apache2ctl graceful` takes down the site and effectively prevents anyone going to it, while still allowing existing php processes started from the server side continue to run.

Comment: @LedZeppelin: it think it returns an HTTP ERROR "server shutting down"